# Is it necessary to initialize a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I am using string in c++. And I am getting unusual answers sometimes if I don't initialize strings.

What is good practice don't initialize the string or If it has to be initialized What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If by "string", you mean `char*`, then yes, they should be (even must be, or at least is it strongly recommended) initialized, like any other variable by the way.

If by "string", you mean `std::string`, then they are initialized to empty string ("") automatically by default (default constructor).

```
std::string str;
std::cout << str; // will print nothing (empty string) for sure
char* str2;
std::cout << str2; // will most likely print garbage or even crash
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard advice in c++ is always initialize all your variables. So yes, you should initialize it. That's just good practice.

When you say "unusual answers" we need more details to offer more advice.

Comment: "The standard advice in c++ is always initialize all your variables." Of course, for class types, this can very often mean "rely on the default ctor to do its job." Which the OP would get if they were using `std::string` (which they are apparently not, and so the question is unanswerable without actual code).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `std::string`, you don't need to "initialize" it because it is automatically initialized to the empty string in its constructor.

If you mean `const char *` or `char *`, then yes, you should initialize them because by default they point to garbage.

Comment: Then you may consider remove it. As you wish.